# How to fix NoResolvedResultException

Tags: maven, jsfunit, shrinkwrap

Cheers!

I getting the following error when trying to run tests on my CI server:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.NoResolvedResultException: Unable to get artifact from the repository, reason: Could not find artifact org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:jar:2.4.1 at specified path /server-data/data/bamboo_home/xml-data/build-dir/PII-BM0-JOB1/myproject-web/src/eclipseLink/eclipselink.jar
```

The **eclipselink.jar** it's not at the pointed location, but it really shouldn't be. The dependecies jars are located on my maven repo, so I don't know why Shrinkwrap is looking for jars in my project's folders...

Also, I was able to run the same tests on my local machine (Mac OS), the error happens when I tried to run the tests in my CI server (AWS Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to fix this problem.

One of my dependencies had a systemPath attribute with a relative path. So I removed that line of the pom and my tests were successful.

```
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
         <version>2.4.1</version>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <systemPath>${basedir}/src/eclipseLink/eclipselink.jar</systemPath> ---> REMOVE THIS LINE
     </dependency>
```